# ajax refresh div with json loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have this ajax function that receive a json var.

```
 $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("FilterCheck","Operatore")",
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: { 'mycheck': mycheck, 'idprot': idprot, 'id': '@Model.id' },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#external-events').empty(); // clear existing items
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                        var div = $('<div class="col-lg-3"><div class="external-event"></div></div>'); // Create new element
                        div.text(item.id + ' ' + item.nome + ' ' + item.cognome); // Set inner text
                        $('#external-events').append(div); // add the new element

                },
```

I would refresh this HTML div:

```
<div id='external-events'>

              @foreach (HAnnoZero.Repositories.utente item in ViewBag.Utenti)
        {
            <div class='col-lg-3'><div class='external-event'>@item.id- @item.cognome @item.nome</div></div>    
        }   </div>
```

With the jquery function "each" i do the loop for more element json.
In this way don't work, write only the first div class='col-lg-3' and not the second. How I can do?
Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to accomplish here ?

Comment: I want rewrite all the div "external-events" with the json var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is here :

```
div.text(item.id + ' ' + item.nome + ' ' + item.cognome); // Set inner text
```

you declared your div with col-lg-3 class with another div external-event inside it.
when you use div.text(), jquery will replace the content of col-lg-3, and not external-event.

you should do :

```
div.find('.external-event').text(item.id + item.nome + item.cognome);
```

EDIT
Or directly :

```
var div = $('<div class="col-lg-3"><div class="external-event">' + item.id + ' ' + item.nome + ' ' + item.cognome + '</div></div>'); // Create new element
$('#external-events').append(div); // add the new element
```

Comment: I can't help you with that, since there is no info in your question about drag&drop :)